# How to calculate the UTM-Latitude-band?

Tags: coordinate-system, utm

I have to convert a coordinate from UTM to MGRS. I think I have the most of it covered, but I have some difficulties to calculate the correct Latitude-band. How can I decide which band the coordinate has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use:

```
zone = math.floor ((lon + 180.0) / 6) + 1
```

Bear with me on that, and I'll check my library

So if

```
lon = -35
lat = 35
```

Then zone will be 25, which I think is correct.  Try it and let me know if it works for you.

There is also:

andrewlesley.freeserve.co.uk/gps/convertr/UTM-MGRS.html

I am sure you can get into the JS and use the code.

```
var UTMzdlChars="CDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXX"; 
function UTMzdl(latDeg) 
{ 
    if(-80<=latDeg&&latDeg<=84) 
    {
        return UTMzdlChars.charAt(Math.floor((latDeg+80)/8));

    }else 
    { 
         //Not normally reached 
         alert("No zdl: UTM is not valid for Lat "+latDeg); 
         return ""; 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already have the zone. What I need is the Latitude-band, thats a letter. It is normally told together with the zone, i.e. 32V. I need to determine the V-part.

Comment: I found this: http://www.andrewlesley.freeserve.co.uk/gps/convertr/UTM-MGRS.html and I am sure you can crack into their js and get the functions out.

Comment: I "cracked" into their js (or looked the source of the site) and found: var UTMzdlChars="CDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXX";

function UTMzdl(latDeg)
{
    if(-80<=latDeg&&latDeg<=84)
        return UTMzdlChars.charAt(Math.floor((latDeg+80)/8));
    else
    {
        alert("No zdl: UTM is not valid for Lat "+latDeg);  //Not normally reached
        return "";
    }
} Thank you!

Comment: No worries, glad to have helped, I'llput it in my answer so you cna upvote me and get me past 2000 ;)

Comment: Ok, I will upvote, if the answer contains that.

Comment: @Mnementh cheers!